# Receive an object in a view associated with multiple foreign keys. Django, Python

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to get values ​​from a class in my models.py file that is bound by multiple intermediate foreign keys.  It looks as shown below.

```
class Masseurs(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=10) #element do zamiany na unikalna nazwe uzytkownika
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    supply = MultiSelectField(choices=CUSTOMER_ACCESS)
    payment_method = MultiSelectField(choices=PAYMENT_METHODS)
    deliver = models.IntegerField()
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX_MASSEURS)

    def average_rating(self):
        all_ratings = [list(map(lambda x: x.rating, self.review_set.all()))]
        return np.mean(all_ratings)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

# these are the days of the week of the year
class WorkTime(models.Model):
    week_of_year = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    masseurs = models.ForeignKey(Masseurs, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.week_of_year

# these are single days
class DayTime(models.Model):
    day_of_week = models.ForeignKey(WorkTime, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    day_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    full_time = models.BooleanField(default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.day_name

# these are individual time units such as ('from 8.00-9.00')
class Time(models.Model):
    day_time = models.ForeignKey(DayTime, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    compartment = models.CharField(max_length=11)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.compartment
```

Now in my view.py using get_object_or_404  I take a single object from the table 'Masseurs' as in the view below.

**views.py**

```
def masseur_detail(request, masseurs_id):
    masseur = get_object_or_404(Masseurs, pk=masseurs_id)
    daytime = Time.objects.select_related('day_time__day_of_week__masseurs').get(id=masseurs_id)
    context = {'masseur': masseur, 'daytime': daytime}
    return render(request, 'masseur/masseur_detail.html', context)
```

Then, using 'daytime' I try to get all the hours of work for a particular masseur. However, he receives the error 'Time matching query does not exist.'

**templates.html**

```
{% for time in daytime.time_set.all %}
<span class="badge badge-lg badge-pill badge-success text-uppercase">11.00- 
  12.00</span>
{% endfor %}
```

How to get all the values ​​from the 'DayTime' table linked by many foreign keys to the individual 'Masseurs' just rendered in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making wrong query for Time. I would have done something like this:

First, update related names:

```
class Time(models.Model):
    # rest of the fields
    day_time = models.ForeignKey(DayTime, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='times')
```

Then, instead of [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related), we need to use [prefetch related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) for daytime, as we are fetching related object via reverse relation:

```
day_time = DayTime.objects.prefetch_related('times').get(day_of_week__masseurs_id=masseurs_id)
```

Advantage of prefetch related is that, it will fetch the related `Time` instances for that `DayTime` object. So we don't need to make extra query to DB.

Now we can use that in template:

```
{% for time in daytime.times.all %}  // updated here
<span class="badge badge-lg badge-pill badge-success text-uppercase">11.00- 
  12.00</span>
{% endfor %}
```

OR

Directly query like this:

```
times = Time.objects.filter(day_time__day_of_week__masseurs_id=masseurs_id)
```

Comment: thank you for an exhaustive answer, when is it worth to use the query set in the view and when to create your own tags for html templates to show such values? is there any difference in how I will do it in terms of performance?

Comment: I think it depends on quantity. in this case(of the question), the 2nd solution is more preferred. But when you want to display all the DayTime objects and its relevant Time objects, then you should use the first solution.